# The title of the button is not changing

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Im trying to change the title of the button with this code but it doesn´t work.
There is no error when I run the app just the title of the button doesn´t change. Just the storyLabel changes

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let StorySt=[story(storyTitle: "you see a fork in the spoon", choice1:"Take a left", choice2: "Take a right"),story(storyTitle: "you see a tiger", choice1: "Shout for dead", choice2: "play dead"),story(storyTitle: "you find a treasure chest", choice1: "Open it", choice2: "Check for traps")]
    @IBOutlet weak var storyLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Choice1Button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Choice2Button: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        storyLabel.text=StorySt[0].storyTitle
        Choice1Button.setTitle(StorySt[0].choice1, for: .normal)
        Choice2Button.setTitle(StorySt[0].choice2, for: .normal)
    }
    @IBAction func choiceMade(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code as text, using proper code formatting - and not as a screenshot -, in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: Unrelated but: Name you variable starting with a lower case and your classes/structs with an uppercase.

Comment: Check you outlet connections in the storyboard

Comment: can you share the code ..?

Comment: I don't find the problem in your code. U need share file nib.

Comment: Check your outlets is connected to storyboard? [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8plfV.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8plfV.png)